# gl::GetAttribLocation() returns -1 despite the attribute being listed as an active attribute?

Tags: opengl, rust, glsl

I have this shaders in OpenGL:

```c
#version 440

in vec3 pos;
in vec3 col;

out vec4 vertexColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.0);
    vertexColor = vec4(col, 1.0);
}
```

And for the fragment:

```c
#version 440 core

out vec4 fragColor;

in vec4 vertexColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = vertexColor;
}
```

I try to get their location with GetAttribLocation.

```
let position_attr = gl::GetAttribLocation(shader_program, "pos".as_ptr() as *const i8);
let color_attr = gl::GetAttribLocation(shader_program, "col".as_ptr() as *const i8);
```

I get this input:

```
4294967295 (-1 unsigned)
1
```

I made this two functions in order to understand the problem.

```
unsafe fn check_active_atributes(shader_program: u32){
    let mut count = 0;
    gl::GetProgramiv(shader_program, gl::ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES, &mut count);

    println!("Number of active attributes: {}", count);
}

fn print_active_attributes(program: gl::types::GLuint) {
    let mut num_active_attrs = 0;
    unsafe {
        gl::GetProgramiv(program, gl::ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES, &mut num_active_attrs);
    }

    println!("Active attributes:");
    for i in 0..num_active_attrs {
        let mut name: [u8; 256] = [0; 256];
        let mut length = 0;
        let mut size = 0;
        let mut gl_type = 0;
        unsafe {
            gl::GetActiveAttrib(
                program,
                i as gl::types::GLuint,
                256,
                &mut length,
                &mut size,
                &mut gl_type,
                name.as_mut_ptr() as *mut gl::types::GLchar,
            );
        }
        let name_str = std::str::from_utf8(&name[..length as usize]).unwrap();
        println!("- {}.", name_str);
    }
}
```

This is what they print:

```
Number of active attributes: 2
Active attributes:
- pos.
- col.
```

The shaders compile fine and don't return any error nor warnings. Any ideas? I'm using linux as OS.

Comment: It would be useful to see the fragment shader here. If 'pos' is returning -1, that would be a bit crazy. If 'col' is returning -1, then I'd assume it's because 'vertexColor' isn't being used in the fragment shader?